# How to get access for WebTelephony API?

Tags: firefox-os

I'm trying to implement a blacklist app for Firefox OS 1.3.

So, I need get access to the ContactManager and the WebTelephony API (for hooking incoming call). But the problem is that the WebTelephony API is available only for certified apps (internal apps).

Is there any way to grant access of WebTelephony API to my app? Or alternative variants?

Comment: Seems problem solves via set field 'type' in manifest as 'certified'.

Comment: After this app is unremovable :(

Answer (score 0):

Currently, the WebTelephony API requires certified permissions. That means that It can not be installed using the window.navigator.mozApps.install() or the Marketplace. However, you could install it using the App Manager or the WebIDE.

In theory, it is possible to uninstall any app using the "App Permissions" panel in the Settings menu. For example, If you want to remove the Homescreen app (do NOT try it, it is only an example!):
[image: App Permissions]
[image: Apps list]
[image: Remove the homescreen]